Unable to get the postgres data in the right format via Kafka, JDBC source connector and pyspark
I have created a table in Postgres:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.sample_a
(
    id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    is_active boolean NOT NULL,
    is_deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    created_by integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    created_ip character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created_dept_id integer NOT NULL,
    updated_by integer,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_ip character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    updated_dept_id integer,
    deleted_by integer,
    deleted_at timestamp with time zone,
    deleted_ip character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    deleted_dept_id integer,
    sql_id bigint NOT NULL,
    ipa_no character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    pe_id bigint NOT NULL,
    uid character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    mr_no character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    site_id integer NOT NULL,
    entered_date date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_patient_dilation PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

and I have inserted the data as below:
INSERT INTO sample_a (id, is_active, is_deleted, created_by, created_at, created_ip, created_dept_id, updated_by, updated_at, updated_ip, updated_dept_id, deleted_by, deleted_at, deleted_ip, deleted_dept_id, sql_id, ipa_no, pe_id, uid, mr_no, site_id, entered_date)
VALUES ('00037167-0894-4373-9a56-44c49d2285c9', TRUE, FALSE, 70516, '2024-10-05 08:12:25.069941+00','10.160.0.76', 4, 70516, '2024-10-05 09:25:55.218961+00', '10.84.0.1',4,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0,0,165587147,'22516767','P5942023',1,'10/5/24');

Now, I have created the JDBC source connector config as below:
   {
  "name": "JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "name": "JdbcSourceConnectorConnector_0",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "********",
    "table.whitelist": "sample_a",
    "mode": "bulk"
  }
}

So when the data is pushed from the DB to the Kafka Topic, I can see the data in the readable format in the Kafka Control Center tab. Since I am using bulk mode, the data is continuously being loaded.
My Problem is when I fetch the data via Pyspark, it is not readable:
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Kafka_Test") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "sample_a") \
    .option("startingOffsets","latest") \
    .load()

df.selectExpr("cast(value as string) as value").writeStream.format("console").start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()

Output:
H00037167-0894-4373-9a56-44c49d2285c9?ڹ??d10.160.0.7??????d10.84.0.0????22516767P5942023¸  

So do I access the specific attributes? Do I need any deserializer class?
TIA.
As per Nimi's suggestion I was able to fetch the schema via the schema registry and tried to use the from_avro method but it gave me this error:
jsonSchema = {"type":"record","name":"sample_a","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},{"name":"is_active","type":"boolean"},{"name":"is_deleted","type":"boolean"},{"name":"created_by","type":"int"},{"name":"created_at","type":{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}},{"name":"created_ip","type":"string"},{"name":"created_dept_id","type":"int"},{"name":"updated_by","type":["null","int"],"default":None},{"name":"updated_at","type":["null",{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}],"default":None},{"name":"updated_ip","type":["null","string"],"default":None},{"name":"updated_dept_id","type":["null","int"],"default":None},{"name":"deleted_by","type":["null","int"],"default":None},{"name":"deleted_at","type":["null",{"type":"long","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}],"default":None},{"name":"deleted_ip","type":["null","string"],"default":None},{"name":"deleted_dept_id","type":["null","int"],"default":None},{"name":"sql_id","type":"long"},{"name":"ipa_no","type":"string"},{"name":"pe_id","type":"long"},{"name":"uid","type":"string"},{"name":"mr_no","type":"string"},{"name":"site_id","type":"int"},{"name":"entered_date","type":{"type":"int","connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date","logicalType":"date"}}],"connect.name": "sample_a"}
df.select(from_avro("value", json.dumps(jsonSchema)).alias("sample_a")) \
    .select("sample_a.*").writeStream.format("console").start()

error:.
     org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Current parse Mode: FAILFAST. To process malformed records as null result, try setting the option 'mode' as 'PERMISSIVE'.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroDataToCatalyst.nullSafeEval(AvroDataToCatalyst.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 70516 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:283)


What converter is your connector using?

Not so sure about this. I am using kafka-jdbc latest connector.

The connector doesn't matter. Look at your property files. What is the key/value converter and why aren't you overwriting the settings?

Even after making the changes to the properties no luck. I referred to this answer made by you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951315/how-to-configure-kafka-connect-use-avro-schema

I can't use localhost since my hostname is schema-registry.

@OneCricketeer could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79128128/unable-to-push-the-data-from-the-written-kafka-topic-to-postgres-table

"Can't use localhost"... Then don't? That answer was just a copy paste of the config in the question. Change any server endpoints and URLs, as needed. The AvroConverter will require a schema registry url and localhost:8081 is the default value

Got it. @OneCricketeer

Finally, I was able to solve the problem using this blog. The author has well explained the concept.
The approach suggested by Nimi was right. There was this magic bytes trick that was missing and treating them the right way helped me to solve the issue.
Will have to read about magic bytes in much detail though.
I would like to Thank OneCricketeer and Nimi for their time. Much Appreciated.

I presume that the value type is not a string - but an Avro record.
That means you can't use string casting to read the byte array like you did:
cast(value as string) as value

Instead you need to follow the avro docs and do something like this:
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro, to_avro

# `from_avro` requires Avro schema in JSON string format.
jsonFormatSchema = open("examples/src/main/resources/sample_a_schema.avsc", "r").read()

df.select(from_avro("value", jsonFormatSchema).alias("sample_a"))\
.select("sample_a.*")\
.writeStream\
.format("console")\
.start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()

I haven't tested it but seems like that's the thing...
Hope this helps!
If you provide the schema - it should probably be something like:
{ "type":"record","name":"sample_a","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},{"name":"is_active","type":"boolean"},{"name":"is_deleted","type":"boolean"},{"name":"created_by","type":"int"},{"name":"created_at","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}},{"name":"created_ip","type":"string"},{"name":"created_dept_id","type":"int"},{"name":"updated_by","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"updated_at","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}],"default":null},{"name":"updated_ip","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"updated_dept_id","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"deleted_by","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"deleted_at","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}],"default":null},{"name":"deleted_ip","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"deleted_dept_id","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"sql_id","type":"long"},{"name":"ipa_no","type":"string"},{"name":"pe_id","type":"long"},{"name":"uid","type":"string"},{"name":"mr_no","type":"string"},{"name":"site_id","type":"int"},{"name":"entered_date","type":{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}}]}

I am not sure where you got the
"connect.version":1,"connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date"

and such - they are not a valid avro AFAIK

I didn't get this line jsonFormatSchema = open("examples/src/main/resources/sample_a_schema.avsc", "r").read() 

How to use this? As per the documentation, we must store the schema in the avro  format and then use it in the code. But I have the schema in my schema-registry so how to re-use that?

@RushHour - you can fetch the schema from schema registry...
For instance you can use the python schema registry client

Thanks, Nimi a lot. Yes, I tried programmatically and I was able to fetch the schema. I have edited the original question with the latest problem I faced after attaching the schema. So please let me know what am I missing.

@RushHour the avro json doesn't look valid to me.
Please try the json I edited in my original message.

I got that Avro from the schema-registry. I used this command to fetch the schema from registry curl -s \  "http://localhost:8081/subjects/sample_a-value/versions/latest/schema" \  | jq .

And your schema is also giving me the same error @Nimi.

@RushHour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry

I have shared my insights sir

Can you please check if created_ip is null or empty - while it should be not null? That's what I see as the error when running locally...

I believe you had the table a little different in the beginning - and there is some "junk" with old schema... try emptying the topic - and inserting new records - and see if that works or not

No its not empty/null. I just verified. It has a value like 10.160.0.76 also I cross-checked the schema from the registry and there is no such constraint for this field {"name":"created_ip","type":"string"}

Also, is there any way without a registry like fetching the schema from the DB record and attaching it to the data loaded from Kafka? Like from_json or something. But I am not sure whether it will work or not because the schema of value is binary

Schema for sample_a never changed. This question is totally focused on this table only sir.

@nimi This approach doesn't even work for the other sample table (another question of mine) you commented on a few hours back.
