Unable to push the data from the written kafka topic to Postgres table
I am trying to load the data written into the Kafka topic into the Postgres table. I can see the topic is receiving new messages every second and also the data looks good.
However, when I use the below JDBC sink configuration it is not able to load the data in the Postgres table:
{
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "name": "JdbcSinkConnectorConnector_0",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "topics": "sample_b",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "********",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "table.name.format": "${topic}",
    "auto.create": "true"
  }
}

Pyspark code that writes the data to Kafka topic:
transformed_df.selectExpr("CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value") \
.writeStream.outputMode(outputMode='Append').format('kafka') \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
.option("topic", "sample_b") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "src/checkpointLoc") \
.start() \
.awaitTermination()

When I checked the Kafka control center tab for this topic sample_b it gives the data in this format:
{
  "id": "00037167-0894-4373-9a56-44c49d2285c9",
  "is_active": true,
  "is_deleted": false,
  "created_by": 70516,
  "created_at": "2024-10-05T13:42:25.069+05:30",
  "created_ip": "10.160.0.76",
  "created_dept_id": 4,
  "updated_by": 70516,
  "updated_at": "2024-10-05T14:55:55.218+05:30",
  "updated_ip": "10.84.0.1",
  "updated_dept_id": 4,
  "sql_id": 0,
  "ipa_no": "0",
  "pe_id": 165587147,
  "uid": "22516767",
  "mr_no": "P5942023",
  "site_id": 1,
  "entered_date": "2024-10-05"
}

Now, I tried to push the data via another Kafka topic named test01. I created the topic via KSQL and pushed the data to it and using the same JDBC sink configuration I was able to push the data to the Postgres table without any issues.
 CREATE STREAM TEST01 (KEY_COL VARCHAR KEY, COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR)
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test01', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO')
 INSERT INTO TEST01 (KEY_COL, COL1, COL2) VALUES ('V',4,'EOO');

The data for test01 looks like the below in the Kafka Control Center tab:
{
  "COL1": {
    "int": 4
  },
  "COL2": {
    "string": "EOO"
  }
}

I can see the schema difference between the two topics. So what exact change do I need to make in the sample_b topic writing so that it matches the test01 payload format?
I don't see any errors in the Kafka Connect logs.

Again, you've not shown your key/value converter settings for Connect, so it's not clear what serialization you're using, but JDBC Sink requires schema/payload fields not plain JSON, some examples here https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/

Sorry, but I didn't get what you mean by key/value converter settings for Connect.  Where can I configure/find this?

Are you asking for something similar to this that I have added in my config? io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter I also tried the same class for key and value both. Also, I tried to use JSON class but didn't help.

Do I need to convert before dumping the data to the Kafka topic?

Also, why did the data of  topictest01 get inserted into the Postgres table without any Serde?

Avro (or Jsonschema, or Protobuf) will work better for Kafka Connect, overall. Plain JSON has no schema information to carry to the database tables. It starts with what your ksql value format is set as, then yes, you should be specifying the value.converter in the connector

The keys are varchar in ksql, so the converter/deserializer should just be StringConverter

Okay, thanks for all that info. It would be useful going forward. However, what should be done exactly in my case? @OneCricketeer

Should I create a topic via KSQL and dump data to that topic via Pyspark? Does it make sense?

I'm not sure how that would help. Since it's not ksql that's enforcing the schema on topic writes. It uses schema on read for streams created from topics. Schemas are only used on ksql INSERT statements, and not enforced by the broker in any way

Ohh Okay cool. Got it. Thanks a lot @OneCricketeer.

SampleB topic is JSON, by usage of to_json Spark function.
test01 topic, is Avro, by usage of VALUE_FORMAT=AVRO in ksqlDB.

Like any Kafka application, serialization formats must match on both ends of the topic... An Avro Deserializer will not accept JSON, and vice versa

it is not able to load the data in the Postgres table

The Connect server has both logs and a /status API. Look at the errors, if there are any.
My suspicion is that you have Kafka connect configured to read Avro data instead of JSON
Configure the converters to fix it. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

make in the sample_b topic writing so that it matches the test01 payload format?

You'd need to_avro function but not the one built into Spark, as that will not work with Confluent's AvroConverter (as you've previously discovered the "magic byte" format)
See https://github.com/absaoss/abris/blob/master/documentation/python-documentation.md

Sure. Let me try it. I will keep you posted.

The question was asking about an external tool where they don't control how it writes to Kafka... You do (via Spark, but it could be any other client)... Ksql supports multiple data formats, such as JSON or JSON_SR (aka Jsonschema +Schema Registry magic-byte format). Plain JSON (schemas disabled) will not with with JDBC because tables must have a schema... You cannot send {"foo": 1} then next record {"foo": {"bar" : 1}} since that's not the same schema... Kafka will happily accept both records, but the database won't (forget ksql and Spark)

Yeah, I deleted my comments but I think due to network issues it didn't get deleted at that point to which you replied. Got it thanks a lot. Also, for abris do we need to pass spark-context and SQL-context still? I don't feel like people still create these objects anymore.

I'm not sure I understand the question. The context is necessary to access py4j functions

Okay and how do I install this library to utilize the methods? I don't see the PyPi package for this library. Should I include in the spark.jars.packages in the form of groupId:artifactid:version? Because I tried something like this not sure if that's the correct way .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0,za.co.absa:abris_2.12:3.3.0")  and it gave me this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: za.co.absa#abris_2.12;3.3.0: not found] 

It's Scala code. Won't be in Pypi... Latest version is za.co.absa:abris_2.12:6.4.1 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/za.co.absa/abris_2.12/6.4.1  You could also download it directly, but that would not pull transitive dependencies https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/za/co/absa/abris_2.12/6.4.1/  However, Avro isn't a requirement. You only need to have data output with a schema that Kafka Connect accepts

Got it. So how to use this library in Python env? or can I try the to_avro Pyspark method?

You're adding it to the Spark JVM classpath, not a Python env... You add the package (of the correct version). You're using the correct code. The version is just wrong. Then follow the docs

Cool. Thanks a lot for all the responses. Really appreciated.
